# Sanitizing for ngModel

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to safely decode some strings via `ngModel`.

I'm currently using `ngSanitize` for outputting it in the view correctly but when using `ngModel`, it completely breaks.

#### API Response

```
{
  id : 1,
  name : 'Gary&#039;s Company'
}
```

#### Controller

```
// Returned from the API
$scope.user = {
  id : 1,
  name : 'Gary&#039;s Company'
};
```

#### View

```
<!-- Since ngModel isn't hooked up to the sanitizer, the text input field is showing the raw ASCII code. -->
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />

<!-- This displays "Gary's Company" correctly. The single quote gets convereted successfully. -->
<span ng-bind-html="user.name"></span>
```

Am I on the right track or is there a better or more direct approach to this?

Comment: Did the answer address your question?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service to decode the value in the controller.

```
$scope.user = {
  id : 1,
  name : 'Gary&#039;s Company'
};
$scope.user.name = $sanitize($scope.user.name);
```

`$sanitize` is not part of the core Angular package and so you need to include `angular-sanitize.js` and add a dependency on the `ngSanitize` module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);
```

Comment: I've tried using the ngSanitize module in this manner and it did not work for me.

Comment: Works for me in 1.6.6. `console.log($sanitize("Hello <script>alert(1);</script> world"));` displays `Hello  world`

Comment: @captain-sparrow anything same available for Angular 2+ ?